# JSON/JQUERY/JS - Access properties from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, javascript-objects

From my PHP processing file I receive back an `object` (`[object Object]`) and I'd like to access it's content's with calls like `data[0].errors` etc, but all tries seem to fail for me.

How may I achieve that?

Here's what the object looks like:

```
" Array
(
    [success] => 
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [companyname] => Company name is required and must have 50 characters at most.
            [logo1] => Logo is required.
            [investment] => First investment amount is required.
            [investment1] => Investment value must be an integer.
            [payment] => Basic wage is required.
            [payment1] => Payment value must be an integer.
            [companytype] => Company type is required.
            [companytype2] => Something is wrong with your company type.
        )

)
"
```

I have to display those `errors` in console div to show the user what has he done wrong.

**EDIT:**

Here's exactly what I get when I `console.log(data)`:
[image: consolelog]

Also here's my AJAX request to make everything clear.

```
        $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST',
                url         : 'processcreatecompany.php',
                data        : formData,
                dataType    : 'json',
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,
                encode      : true
            }).done(function(data) {

                console.log(data);
            }).fail(function(data) {

                console.log(data);

        })
```

Comment: Is the recieved data a string? Exactly that string?

Comment: what i receive is actually `[object Object]`, thanks to Chrome developers menu i can actually see that there is the array, ill screenshot it and show you to make it clearer. ill edit question in a second @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: seems that the problem is in the PHP part, you should post the code

Comment: What have you tried and What errors are you getting?

Comment: Where are you trying to access the `data[0].errors`? It seems the problem has something to do with the asynchronous nature of `$.ajax`.

Comment: @LohmarASHAR to make it clearer I've posted it here: http://codepad.org/JYf3Z0mu

Comment: @che-azeh in fact I'm getting no errors, still i just can't access this objects properties to put them into <div> console. I've tried accesing it like data[0].errors, data['errors'], data.companyname - not working tho

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I've been trying to access it through `console.log(data[0].errors)` etc in my `ajax` `.success` part (tried in `.fail` too)

Comment: In your PHP you should json encode your `$data['errors']` array and return that to your javascript.  Then, in your success callback in your AJAX call, you can parse the json string response into an object, and access the way you're expecting

Comment: @Wrinn thanks you, just as LohmarASHAR said, points for you too, thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as expected the problem is in the php part ... you are doing a `print_r` of the objects which gives that output that it's not json

you should use `json_encode` to return the `$data` object/array, so instead of

```
print_r($data['success']);
print_r($data['errors']);
```

you should have (also you should add the content type header )

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

**Later edit:** without the header you usually get the response as `text/plain` in `data.responseText`, as in your screenshot, and and you will have to do the JSON parsing "by hand". Adding the header makes jQuery do the parsing automatically and you'll have the response as an object in `data.response<something I dont recall now>`

Comment: wow, I can't believe i make such silly mistakes... :) still I'd never get to it since my knowledge is pretty limited - thanks for contributing and helping me out @LohmarASHAR ! Much appreciated!